# SELECT mysql SET column as BIT STRING?

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1;
```

I get results as comma separated strings (column1 is of type SET):

```
'result4,result7,result24'
'result2,result15,result36'
```

etc...

Since mysql SET type is just a 64 BIT string AFAIK - how would I get values as bit string / bit mask?

```
SELECT function_that_converts_to_bit_string( column1 ) FROM table1;
```

So result would be:

```
100100101110000101110
101000110110000101110
100001111100110001110
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select bin(cast(column1 as decimal)) from table1;
```

Comment: I tried it at SQLfiddle and it displayed numbers, although they were in decimal. But I just edited it to display in binary.

Comment: YES. this works great.  SELECT BIN(column1+0) from table1;. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype and collation for column1?

There is a binary datatype (BINARY itself or BLOB) that you can use to get binary data like so. Also the collation should be set to anything (latin1, utf-8 etc.)-bin  The binary collation from whatever collation set you are using, instead of case insensitive (-ci) or case sensitive (-cs) variants.

Comment: apologies, I didn't see it in the OP... how about the collation?

Comment: utf8-general-ci ... alhough - not sure if that's relevant for set type.

Comment: I think it is relevant if you want to get binary data out of it. The query posted by Barmar should work if you change your collation to utf8-bin